set background color of the part of DialogFragment with Pos/Neg buttons?
I've got a DialogFragment which I create like this:
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    FragmentActivity act = getActivity();
    LayoutInflater inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);

    // (...)
    
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_about, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    
    TextView tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_title, null);
    builder.setCustomTitle(tv);
    
    builder.setPositiveButton( R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
        // something
        }
      });

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();

    // some more stuff
    }

Now, the dialog works ok functionality-wise - and I can adjust the color of the background of the title part by setting appropriate value for 'android:background' in the 'R.layout.dialog_title' XML; I can also set appropriate background color for the main part of the dialog (defined by R.layout.dialog_about).
However, the lower part where the 'OK' positive button is, stays grey. Problem is that I don't know where this grey comes from and how to change it.
Same goes for the background of a PopupWindow I create elsewhere in the code; I simply do
    final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_popup, null);
    mPopup = new PopupWindow(act);
    mPopup.setContentView(layout);

where R.layout.settings_popup has the 'background' attribute undefined, and the PopupWindow's background comes out transparent grey. Again, this grey must come from somewhere? How to change it?
